How do I unwrap Wyckoff positions of a crystal into the XYZ coordinates?
I am trying to understand how to use the Wyckoff positions from the Bilbao Crystallographic Server and I am wondering if someone could help with some confusion.
The example material I am looking at is CsGeI3.And I am looking at the CIF file in VESTA. (https://legacy.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-28377/)
In VESTA, the structure parameters are shown is below:

So Cs and Ge both have Wyckoff positions of 3a, which means that there are 3 of them in the unit cell. I has a Wyckoff site of 9b, which means that there are 9 in the unit cell.
To figure out the actual coordinates of the elements, I go to the Bilbao Crystallographic Server and search for the R3m Wycoff position table (shown below):

So the positions of the Cs atoms are: [0,0, 0.91099], [2/3, 1/3, 1/3+0.91099], [1/3, 2/3, 2/3+0.91099] and similar for Ge?
What do I do with the positions for 9b? I don't see how the x,y,z positions as shown in vesta get matched to the positions in the Wyckoff table.
My attempt is the following: For (x, -x, z) in the Wyckoff table I get the position (0.00347, -0.00347, 0.9133) using the structure parameters from VESTA. Is this correct? The 9b positions in the Wyckoff table don't mention the y coordindate which confuses me.
